Date.civil not returning a valid data as under previous Rails version
When migrating a Rails application to 7.0, the following statement processed as expected:
date = Date.civil(params["date_of_birth(1i)"].to_i,params["date_of_birth(2i)"].to_i,params["date_of_birth(3i)"].to_i)
However upon migrating to Rails 7.0 and Ruby 3.1.2 , on a form where f.date_select :date_of_birth is used,
intercepting the value of puts params["date_of_birth(1i)"] returns nil in the log,
and interceptiong puts params["date_of_birth(1i)"].to_i  returns 0 in the log.
The log registers for this action:
Processing by UsersController#results_dob as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "[date_of_birth(3i)]"=>"23", "[date_of_birth(2i)]"=>"10", "[date_of_birth(1i)]"=>"1970", "commit"=>"Invia"}

How can those parameters be processed then?

params["[date_of_birth(1i)]"]. Why the square brackets were added though, I don't know.

looks like a bug with date_select. why aren't you using date_field instead.

@Alex  through experience and observation, date_field causes a lot more user actions when having to deal with about 80 years of dates.  It is definitely better when the scope of search is limited to 5-10 years; then it gradually becomes more work for the user.

you can work around the issue by having scope or actual model in your form: form_with url: "/", scope: "user" do ... and use params["user"]["date_of_birth(1i)"]
